# Apache Spark Unpersist and Persist

Tags: apache-spark

I have been running a very large use cases and due to resource constraint, I have to limit the no. of data being processed at a given time. So running a counter for loop such as 1 to 10 and for every run I process, say 200000 rows.

My question is, if my source has 1M rows, I would end up processing for 5 runs (1M/ 200000). And I have multiple sources also.
So, for eg.

```
Source A has 1M rows
Source B has 2M rows.
```

When i am in the loop for each Source, say,

```
for (source in Sources) {
  val rddSource = spark.read.table(source)
  rddSource.persist
  rddSource.count // to persist the above rdd

  while (counter < 5) {
       //process every 200000 rows with the above persisted rddSource

    }
}
```

I want to persist the data as shown above.that will help to run Source A for every 5 time each with 200000 rows.

But for next iteration of for loop with the Source B, does it replace the previously cached {rddSource} or should I need to have something like this

```
for (source in Sources) {
      val rddSource = spark.read.table(source)
      rddSource.unPersist
      rddSource.persist

      rddSource.count // to persist the above rdd

      while (counter < 5) {
           //process every 200000 rows with the above persisted rddSource

        }
    }
```

Comment: Spark cleans cached DataFrame automatically when it goes out of scope. If you want to do this immediately you have to call `unpersist()` on DataFrame which you called `persist()` on. In your case you have to call `unpersist()` at the end of the `for` loop, after `while`.

Comment: I would love do that, unfortunately, the Sources could be many and the purpose is to reuse when the same source comes up again. eg. Source A, Source B, Source C, Source A, Source B, Source D like that..